# How do I concisely write x = x - 4 unless x is less than 0, in which case x = 0?

Tags: ruby, increment, ternary-operator, pagination, decrement

I am doing some pagination and can do `@next_images_to_paginate += 4` without a problem.

But `@previous_images_to_paginate -= 4` doesn't because I can get negative numbers.

I can't use absolute because I want -1, -2 and -3 to be 0.

Something like:

```
((@previous_images_to_paginate -= 4) < 0) ? 0 : (@previous_images_to_paginate -= 4)
```

but I would like something less wordy.

The page being created is not appropriate for `will_paginate`, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about using the `max` function from an array

```
x = [x-4,0].max
```